# C# Download the sound of a youtube video

Tags: c#, youtube, mp3

I can download a video from youtube but I want the sound only. How can I do that?

Code I have for downloading the video (Using VideoLibrary):

```
        YouTube youtube = YouTube.Default;
        Video vid = youtube.GetVideo(txt_youtubeurl.Text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());
```

Comment: have you tried YoutubeExtractor? It can extract audio files.

Comment: Why dont u just download the whole video and after the download is completed extract the audio wav file using Graphedit ?

Comment: just FYI, on youtube's TOS: "You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content."

Comment: There are few ffmpeg .NET libraries, you might want to try one of those.

Comment: @Steve I read that before I was starting this. It is just to add experience and a fun school project. Not planning on using it in large quantities.

Comment: @JoshC you are violating the ToS regardless of what you use it for.. just saying

Comment: I have created youtuber, is a mp3 downloader full source code https://itbackyard.com/youtuber/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Install the **NuGet** packages: `MediaToolkit` and `VideoLibrary`, it will allow you to do the conversion by file extension.

```
var source = @"<your destination folder>";
var youtube = YouTube.Default;
var vid = youtube.GetVideo("<video url>");
File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());

var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = source + vid.FullName };
var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{source + vid.FullName}.mp3" };

using (var engine = new Engine())
{
    engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

    engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm, only downside is that you have to download the original file first but I can deal with that.

Comment: @JoshC Yeah, I was just now looking for another library that can take a stream and convert it in memory. I'll update the answer if I find it.

Comment: @JoshC little trick: if you want the best audio, invoke `GetVideos` and use `OrderByDescending` on bitrate.

Comment: Awesome, how do I invoke it?

Comment: It's exposed by the `YouTube` object.

Comment: Just to add note regarding getting all videos. Method is called `GetAllVideos(string videoUri)`

Comment: Please note: Nuget 'Install-Package VideoLibrary' is also required.

Comment: I have This Exception :-( The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: How to select the quality of video?

Comment: The request exit with no exception in vid.GetBytes() for no reason

Answer (score 4):

The above code works awesome you don't need to download the video first I created this procedure so when rookies like myself see this makes it easier to use.
You need the nuget packages `MediaToolkit` and `VideoLibrary`.

example url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzm5llVmR2E
example path just needs a path to save file to.
just add the name of the mp3 file to save

Hope this helps someone I have tested this code;

```
private void SaveMP3(string SaveToFolder, string VideoURL, string MP3Name)
{
    var source = @SaveToFolder;
    var youtube = YouTube.Default;
    var vid = youtube.GetVideo(VideoURL);
    File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());

    var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = source + vid.FullName };
    var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{MP3Name}.mp3" };

    using (var engine = new Engine())
    {
        engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

        engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: @penguin. I am getting there is no argument given to path in MediaFile

Comment: @user123456 ensure you set the Filename property. Like `MediaFile inFile = new MediaFile("PATH TO FILE");` or `MediaFile inFile = new MediaFile(){ Filename = "PATH TO FILE" };`; both are the same. Then do the same for the outputFile. I am guessing the Filename property is null for one of them. Make sure that whatever you are setting the filename to is not null.

Comment: I fixed it by using using MediaToolkit.Model;

Comment: @Penguin can I download the file

Comment: @Penguin Not working in azure

Answer (score 3):

Ok found a better way the above code didn't normalize the audio posting it for others.
First Add Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoConverter/ 
To Convert MP4 to MP3

```
 // Client
        var client = new YoutubeClient();
        var videoId = NormalizeVideoId(txtFileURL.Text);
        var video = await client.GetVideoAsync(videoId);
        var streamInfoSet = await client.GetVideoMediaStreamInfosAsync(videoId);
        // Get the best muxed stream
        var streamInfo = streamInfoSet.Muxed.WithHighestVideoQuality();
        // Compose file name, based on metadata
        var fileExtension = streamInfo.Container.GetFileExtension();
        var fileName = $"{video.Title}.{fileExtension}";
        // Replace illegal characters in file name
        fileName = RemoveIllegalFileNameChars(fileName);
        tmrVideo.Enabled = true;
        // Download video
        txtMessages.Text = "Downloading Video please wait ... ";

        //using (var progress = new ProgressBar())
        await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(streamInfo, fileName);

        // Add Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoConverter/ To Convert MP4 to MP3
        if (ckbAudioOnly.Checked)
        {
            var Convert = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
            String SaveMP3File = MP3FolderPath + fileName.Replace(".mp4", ".mp3");
            Convert.ConvertMedia(fileName, SaveMP3File, "mp3");
            //Delete the MP4 file after conversion
            File.Delete(fileName);
            LoadMP3Files();
            txtMessages.Text = "File Converted to MP3";
            tmrVideo.Enabled = false;
            txtMessages.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (ckbAutoPlay.Checked) { PlayFile(SaveMP3File); }
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

based on this topic, i have developed a simple and dumb program to Download a youtube playlist. Hope this helps someone. It's just a Main.cs file: [Youtube Playlist Downloader - Mp4 & Mp3](https://gist.github.com/leandro-almeida/40e683531c768bd29622a2b7ec0bfdba)

Comment: I just had avoid using ExtrairLinksPlaylist(conteudo); so I worte:

            var links = GetVideoURLS(conteudo);

              private static List<string> GetVideoURLS(string conteudo)
        {
            var linksPlaylist = new List<string>();
            
            
                foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(conteudo, "\"videoId\":\"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\",\"playlistId\""))
                {
                linksPlaylist.Add("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+match.Groups[1].Value);
                }
          
            return linksPlaylist;
        }

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using a method. I tried `SaveMP3()` but it had some problems. 
This worked for me: `

```
 private void SaveMP3(string SaveToFolder, string VideoURL, string MP3Name)
        {
            string source = SaveToFolder;
            var youtube = YouTube.Default;
            var vid = youtube.GetVideo(VideoURL);
            string videopath = Path.Combine(source, vid.FullName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(videopath, vid.GetBytes());

            var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(source, vid.FullName) };
            var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(source , $"{MP3Name}.mp3")  };

            using (var engine = new Engine())
            {
                engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);


                engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
            }


            File.Delete(Path.Combine(source, vid.FullName));

        }
```

`